# How can I prevent my C# COM client from spawning a separate instance of my C++ COM server, which is already running as a Windows service?

Tags: c#, c++, com, windows-installer, registry

I'm updating some legacy code that involves an old custom COM server installed as a Windows service. While I was able to compile the code on a modern version of Visual Studio and rewrite the client, I'm encountering an issue where the client is spawning its own instance of the already-running service instead of accessing the local Windows service running as the Local System. Because the spawned process runs under the client code user, it doesn't have access to the service's capabilities.

I've verified that the COM object is being exposed by the Windows service, and I believe I have all the necessary registry entries.

Is there something I'm missing, or has anyone else encountered this issue before?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/ne-combaseapi-regcls (REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE vs REGCLS_SINGLEUSE)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, I wondered this, but came to the conclusion it was set correctly as the server service should be able to have multiple clients (unless I am mistaking what this means). However, I tried changing from MULTIPLEUSE to SINGLEUSE, and now it spawns TWO extra instances instead of one, which I didn't expect :)